# Unity:How to Sync Line renderer in multiplayer?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am building a multiplayer game using unity, In the game the line renderer is only visible in the host machine but is not visible in the other client devices,how to sync the line renderer so that it is visible in all the connected devices.

[image: Representation of the line renderer]

Comment: Is there a networkIdentity on it?

Comment: yes the player has the network identity

Comment: I meant, on the object with the line renderer. I believe every networked objects should have the networkidentity component

Comment: Yes it does...!

Comment: Can you check it really is instanted for both players?

Comment: Without code we cannot realy help you, but we can help you what to check for.

1. Is LineRenderer spawned on client
2. Has LineRenderer good values set (position, color, material etc...)
3. Are you updating thise value of LineRenderer by any means